# Algorithm of naming embedded Pictures in OpenOffice

Tags: algorithm, openoffice.org, checksum, image

I need to embed images inside OpenOffice Text documents without the help of OpenOffice itself. For that I need to work directly inside the zip archive and modify the appropriate xml files. The problem I have now is that OpenOffice stores embedded pictures inside a picture folder and asigns a unique name to them according to the information in the picture.

Filenames look as following:

```
10000000000000FF000000D84ABBAECB.jpg
```

This filename is divided into 4 parts at 8 Byte per part and ending with the file extension.

```
10000000 000000FF 000000D8 4ABBAECB
^        ^        ^        ^
unknown  height   width    checksum
```

My problem now is that I have no clue what kind of checksum algorithm is used.

Comment: This is not related to embedded software but I do not have enough rep to retag.

Comment: I removed the embedded tag to not confuse people looking for embedded software related questions.

Comment: What happens when you just use a different algorithm to determine file names? Does OpenOffice.org care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the [specification](http://xml.openoffice.org/xml_specification.pdf) reveals no special rules for naming embedded pictures. I guess you can name them however you like (within sensible boundaries).

Comment: While this is true I have the problem that, when the template is opened in OpenOffice, the embedded pictures will be renamed. This makes it hard to identify specific pictures later, if I have saved them under an other name.

Comment: Have you checked that OpenOffice.org keeps the filenames in templates if they conform to their internal name format? If not, you have to look for another way to identify your images anyway.

Comment: Yes I have checked this. The same file is always named the same way internally. Despite the fact when I add it or in which document I add it. If it is inserted directly in the archive with its original name (let's say abc.jpeg) and the all xml files are changed accordingly, it will show in OpenOffice. But after the next save of the document in OO the internal name will be given to the file.

Comment: @Aurril I'm considering using a SHA1 signature externally to track images which are renamed like this.

Answer (score 0):

You cat set your own file names by adding the routes to the content.xml and manifest.xml files (META-INF/manifest.xml).

Comment: This lets you construct a valid document but as soon as you save it, OOo will rename all the files (and keep the old ones around too).